AI SDK 'responseMessages' is deprecated
I've been using the responseMessages return value for the generateText and `streamText' methods for a while now but apparently it's deprecated. What do I use instead?
https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/ai-sdk-core/tools-and-tool-calling#response-messages
This message is appearing in VS Code when using the 'ai' import:

Code:
import { generateText } from "ai";
import { openai } from "@ai-sdk/openai";

/**
 * Service class for handling AI interactions
 */
export class AIService {
  /**
   * Get AI response for user input
   * @param input - User's text input
   * @returns AI generated response
   */
  static async getResponse(input: string): Promise<string> {
    const { text, responseMessages } = await generateText({
      model: openai("gpt-4-turbo"),
      prompt: "What is love?",
    });

    return text;
  }
}


It looks like there was a refactoring which moved responseMessages to response.messages, see https://github.com/vercel/ai/pull/3343 :

Summary

Add headers to LanguageModelMetadata and deprecate LanguageModelResponseMetadata
Add messages to response for streamText and generatetext, and deprecate responseMessages
Add response.messages to StepResult (messages for each step are availalbe)
Refactor implementation to use changing responseMessages and fixed initialPrompt


See the changes in the source file https://github.com/vercel/ai/blob/dce415884159ffe9484b566652da5bd24dc67b49/packages/ai/core/generate-text/generate-text-result.ts#L52:

/**
@deprecated use `response.messages` instead.
 */
readonly responseMessages: Array<CoreAssistantMessage | CoreToolMessage>;


The "old" property is marked as @deprecated because of this.
